# bit.ly Pro "out of" Clicks Statistics

Tags: bit.ly

I use bit.ly Pro to view link statistic of my shorten links. In the overview you see to each link the click rate and it states for example: "1 out of 4"
What does this 4 mean? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that 1 people click on link on your twitter and 4 people click on link overall.